# remove CSS file from everything but "append" to a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lets say I have a document with CSS file which applies to all elements in the document.
Is it possible to remove and/or append this file in a way that it will effect a certain div only and not the complete document?

Comment: yes - use ID for the div, and give CSS specific to that div

Comment: Can you be more specific, both in your question and CSS?

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure how to be more specific..(I would if I could)

Comment: how would you remove the css file? manually or by function ?

Comment: You _could_ use an iframe and load that specific div and the css inside that iframe.

Comment: @Ejay That would fail because sometimes a bit of its styling depends on it parents or whatever.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the stylesheet to div something like this `$(div).append?(css-file to this);`

Comment: So my only option is to do it all manually....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference.... Really would like to avoid that..

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a large div with lots of elements and you want to apply a lot of style rules contained in a css file to those elements only, so using the div id selector is not so straight-forward.

One little known feature of HTML5 is **Scoped CSS**. It's an attribute for style blocks. The style block with the scoped attribute will overwrite the global styles generally found in the head (whether in a style block or linked stylesheet), but only on the sibling/descendent elements inside the same parent.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/style.html#style.attrs.scoped

http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: Hi thanks, that is good one, to bad I really want to include IE8 support for my project..

Comment: I see. Yes it is html5 so it is not compatible with IE older versions. However, for general reference or if you still need it and there is no other way, have a look at these 'hacks' to enable html5 in IE or use the jquery-scoped-css plugin.

http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/
http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/
https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override css styling

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 #id_of_element{
    /* add styles */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is that I don't know what the styling is upfront. And its not so much about adding style to the div, but preserving its style and removing the styling from everything else

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do anything to the location of where the css file is appended in the DOM to make it applicable for a specfic DIV. What you can do, is what other already answered....give your div some id or class (or find another way to uniquely identify it) and make sure all your specific CSS is falling under that selector.